# Client assertion audience claim does not match Realm issuer

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I can successfully retrieve a token for my app via an HTTP POST request in PostMan from login.windows.net with the resource param set to "a0e1e353-1a3e-42cf-a8ea-3a9746eec58c". This sets the "aud" field in the JWT token to the same value. The marketplaceapi endpoint I'm authenticating with rejects any tokens that have a different aud value.

When I use ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder in C# to retrieve a token with my cert, I'm using .WithClientAssertion() to set the aud to the same value following the example [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-Assertions). But whenever I try setting the aud value and call .AcquireTokenForClient(), I get this error

> Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: 'A configuration issue
> is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server
> for details.You can modify the configuration in the application
> registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for
> details.
> Original exception: AADSTS700023: Client assertion audience
> claim does not match Realm issuer. Review the documentation at
> https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials
> . Trace ID: 4cb57c15-6a25-4baa-b88c-2e92caf71100 Correlation ID:
> 17f9f513-3bec-4ecc-9b2f-7e01a9897e93 Timestamp: 2020-09-16 05:19:31Z'

I tried setting the scope to that value, but then I get an invalid scope error. What do I need to do to get the correct aud value in my JWT token?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and it was solved by adding .WithSendX5C(true) to acquire token.

Confidential client created as

```
ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(this.applicationClientId)
           .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, this.tenantId)
           .WithCertificate(certificate)
           .Build();
```

Acquire token as

```
await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
            .WithSendX5C(true)
            .ExecuteAsync();
```